# import exception with geopy

Tags: python, pydev, geopy

I use the geopy library to work with locations. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy

I installed and used it for the first time and it worked fine. The next couple of days, I executed the same code and there was an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
from geopy import geocoders
ImportError: cannot import name geocoders
```

I also tried to re-install the library and re-set the interpreter path. I use windows 7, eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) with pydev. Python version is 2.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

Instead use:

```
import geopy.geocoders
```

or even:

```
import geopy.geocoders as geocoders
```

Edit:

Here are the complete steps to download and run the example:

Open terminal and run the command:

```
pip install geopy
```

When this is complete, make a file in the same directory called example.py and
then copy the following code into it:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

print(location.raw)
```

Then run the file from the terminal using:

```
python example.py
```

And you should see the correct output

Comment: It did not work. I also tried the code in Eclipse pydev in Ubuntu. 
But anther thing is if I open Terminal, copy and paste line by line, then it works!!! What goes wrong here?

Comment: if you installed the package using pip then it will be available to you from your terminal, but it may not be available from pydev if that uses a different python environment, try creating a python file and copying the Geocoding example from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy, then try run it from your command line

Comment: It is hard to explain in words. I run the code again and capture the screen so that you can see what is going on. I upload here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyv6op0m5i540je/geopy_errors.pdf?dl=0